# OPC simaticNET ProgID unknown

Tags: c#, plc, opc

I have a C# application that is running as an OPC client, with a Siemens S7-300 PLC as the device with which it needs to communicate over a DP coupler (profibus). I am using Siemens OPC Server running on a CPC to facilitate the communications, but in order to do this, I have to feed my application some OPC server information, including the Server Name and Server ProgID (which I've been told is also known as the CLSID?)

The goal is to be able to load my application onto the CPC, run it with the PLC connected to the CPC via profibus, and then have communication capabilities between software & PLC.

As a result of the research I've done so far, I have my Server Name set to `localhost/OPC.SimaticNET.1` and the Server ProgID set to `{B6EACB30-42D5-11D0-9517-0020AFAA4B3C}` so that my actual OPC connection string looks like `opcda://localhost/OPC.SimaticNET.1/{B6EACB30-42D5-11D0-9517-0020AFAA4B3C}`but my program cannot read or write through the OPC server. Since I am using the DP couplers specifically, I am unsure if I should instead be using `OPC.SimaticNET.DP.1` and its associated `{5F30A70F-8256-4ee3-8FCD-A65CF62C25CA}` CLSID. I have played around with both ideas, but neither seems to yield solid results.

What might I try to get my application to correctly communicate with the OPC server?

Comment: A client typically *requires* either a ProgID or a CLSID; it may *allow* you to specify both, but really just one is needed, because any ProgID has first to be converted to a CLSID (using registry or OpcEnum) to be usable for OPC communications. But this is just a note. My question is: What kind of error symptoms you get? Any specific error message?

Comment: Well the errors are a little hard to interpret... the OPC communications for this application weren't written by me, and it's setup to send out a "failed to write" error if it can't get a solid connection for whatever reason. So whether it's because it can't connect or I'm trying to pass an invalid tag, it will produce the same message.  I'm mostly just trying to figure out what I need to setup to make a general connection to a Siemens OPC server using a DP coupler and go from there. The ambiguity of it all has been pretty frustrating thus far.

Comment: There are many things that can go wrong. You wrote that you have not written the code that reports the errors, but you have not written that you cannot modify the code. If you have control of the code, I would debug it or put some tracing into it so that the precise place of the error is known, and any detailed info around it. It is quite possible that you have the ProgIDs/CLSIDs correct, but the problem is in something else.